# Simple question about orthogonalization of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, orthonormal, change-of-basis

If I want to find the orthonormal basis $C(A)$ of a 4x3 matrix whose, do I perform Gram Schmidt using the columns or rows as the vectors?

Comment: Columns is the conventional way.

Comment: @Fightclub1995 Ok. Will rows return the same result?

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: Applying Gram Schmidt to the rows yields a basis for the row space $R(A) = C(A^T)$, which need not coincide with the column space.